# string template format unknown

Tags: string, templates, string-interpolation

i'm going crazy, i have a string that should represent some kind of template that i should popolate with values in this format:

> The Notes bear interest from and including ${expected_issuance_date}
>   at the rate of ${interest_rate} per cent. per annum, payable $${If
>   ${Coupon_Period} = [Quarterly] ; Insert}{quarterly}$${If
>   ${Coupon_Period} = [Semi-annual] ; Insert}{semi-annually}$${If
>   ${Coupon_Period} = [Annual] ; Insert}{annually} in arrear on
>   ${Issue_Date; Day}${Issue_Date; Month} every $${If ${Coupon_Period} =
>   [Quarterly] ; Insert}{3}$${If ${Coupon_Period} = [Semi-annual] ;
>   Insert}{6}$${If ${Coupon_Period} = [Annual] ; Insert}{12} months (each
>   an Interest Payment Date).

I cannot find any java (or javascript) library that seems using this format, does anyone have some hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's GLML.

General-purpose Legal Mark-up Language (GLML) is an open-specification mark-up language that allows legal documents to become machine-readable and facilitates automation of capital markets. GLML is being supported and developed by the standalone GLML Consortium, which comprises leading capital markets law firms, banks, custodians, central securities depositories, exchanges, paying agents and ratings agencies.

Source: https://www.nivaura.com/nivaura-hosts-successful-industry-event-and-product-launch/